# the where ___ in ____ sql command in my query using php

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to take a user's input of #,@, or just normal statements and then pull those results from a SQL database if the search results exist in the "query" column of a table called "job" in my database. Here is the error I am getting:

```
 Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'
```

Here's my code:

```
$result_all = $_POST['result_name'];
$result_all_array= explode(',',$result_all);
$query = "select last_count, query, job_id from twitterinblack46.job where 

query in (".$result_all_array.") order by last_count desc;";
 $result= mysql_query($query);

if($result === FALSE) {
die(mysql_error());
 }
 else{
 //Sets up table
 echo "<table border='1'
 <tr>
 <th>Job ID</th>
 <th>Last Count</th>
 <th>Result</th>
 </tr>";

 //Populates table
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo"<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row["job_id"] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . ltrim($row["last_count"],'0') . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . str_replace(array('%23', '%40', '%20', 'q='), array('#','@',' ',''), 

$row['query']) . "</td>";
echo "<tr>";
 }
echo "</table>";
```

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

---

Update:

Here was the confusion, I did not forget to copy the $ for query. "query" is the name of the column I want to get the information from in my query. So what I am saying is, what is the difference between these two sets of code and why doesn't it work for the first query?

Code that doesn't work:

```
$result_all= $_POST['result_name'];
$query = "select last_count, query, job_id from twitterinblack46.job where 
query in (".$result_all.") order by last_count desc;";
$result= mysql_query($query);
```

Code that does work:

```
$job_id_all= $_POST['job_id'];
$query = 'select last_count, query, job_id from twitterinblack46.job where job_id in 
('.$job_id_all.') order by last_count desc;';
$result= mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: Don't use the mysql_ functions and don't take the data from a POST variable and plop it directly into the SQL.

Comment: Read about SQL injection and how to prevent it!

Comment: You should follow the suggestions from the above comments. So, what is the error at the moment?

Comment: I am getting this error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%23sandusky) order by last_count desc' at line 1

Comment: I've merged your original code back into your question as it stands - it was difficult to work out, as a new reader, what you had originally asked. If you have an answer to a question, please don't replace a question's text with a new update - either add an addendum on the end, or ask a brand new question.

Answer (score 0):

It is obviously a problem of the form input, being multiple checkboxes checked for example.
Try this in both queries:

```
$result_all= implode(',', mysql_escape_string($_POST['result_name']));
$query = "select last_count, query, job_id from twitterinblack46.job where query in (".$result_all.") order by last_count desc;";
$result= mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: Yeah but here is my code for the job_id search query and it works perfectly fine:
$job_id_all= $_POST['job_id'];
$job_id_array= explode(',',$job_id_all);
$query = 'select last_count, query, job_id from twitterinblack46.job where job_id in ('.$job_id_all.') order by last_count desc;';

Comment: Yes, exactly, because you are not writing the job_id_array in the query, which is an array, but the posted string.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Can you please go into more detail because to me the two queries are exactly the same except the contents of the array's are different and one works while the other doesn't.

Comment: In the code you wrote to me, you are not using the array variable. I'm going to post it as part of the answer, so that you can see what I mean.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that my code was incorrect from the actual code I am using. I have edited it in the question. However it still does not work.